# The button onclickon eventlisteners is not working?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I'm practicing javascript and I copied and pasted the code but still not working. Have I missed something? I created a notes taking app and when the user clicks the button, the note should show but it doesn't do anything.

[image]

```
const addBox = document.querySelector(".add-box");
const popUpBox = document.querySelector(".popup-box");
const closeIcon = document.querySelector("header i");
const titleTag= document.querySelector("input");
const descTag= document.querySelector("textarea");
const addBtn = popUpBox.querySelector("button");
const popupTitle = document.querySelector("header p");

    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",     "August", "   September", "October", "November", "December"];

addBox.addEventListener("click", function(){
    titleTag.focus();
     popUpBox.classList.add("show")
 });

  closeIcon.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
     popUpBox.classList.remove("show")
 });

addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     let noteTitle = titleTag.value,
     noteDesc = descTag.value;
      if (noteTitle || noteDesc){


        let dateObj = new Date(),
        month = months[dateObj.getMonth()],
        day = dateObj.getDate(),
        year = dateObj.getFullYear();


        let noteInfo = {
            title: noteTitle, description: noteDesc,
            date: `${month} ${day} ${year}`
        }  
     if(!isUpdate){
             notes.push(noteInfo);
        }else {
            isUpdate = false;
            notes[UpdateId] = noteInfo
        } 
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
        closeIcon.click()
        showNotes()
     }
});

function showNotes() {
        document.querySelectorAll(".note").forEach(note => note.remove())
      notes.forEach((note, index) => {
        let liTag = `<li class="note">
          <div class="details">
              <p>${note.title}</p>
              <span>${note.description}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom-content">
              <span>${note.date}</span>
              <div class="settings">
                <i onclick="showMenu(this)" class="uil uil-ellipsis-h"></i>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li onclick="updateNote(${index}, '${note.title}',    '${note.description}')">      <i class="uil uil-pen"></i>Edit</li>
                    <li onclick="deleteNote(${index})"><i class="uil uil-trash">  </i>Delete</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
         </li>`;
         addBox.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", liTag)
      });
    }

    showNotes(); 

    closeIcon.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        titleTag.value = "";
        descTag.value = "";
    });
```

It is mostly abt oop, eventlisteners, and DOM. I'd appreciate answers, thank you so much.

Comment: When you open your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  Using the script debugger, is the event handler function invoked at all?  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Inside `showNotes` where are notes been declared? Change to get notes from localstorage right in the beginning.

Comment: I can see you are saving notes to `localStorage`, but not fetching it from localStorage. on Your `showNotes` function, might want to do something like this
let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('notes')), then you can loop over as you are doing now.